# Nivo slider not working in wordpress jquery

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nivo-slider

I have added nivo slider plugin to wordpress however it doesn't move past the git loading file.I believe the problem is in the way i am loading the jquery.

I have included the javascript jquery.nivo.slider.js file in the js folder inside my theme folder.
 In the header.php i am using this inside the head tags:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/bootstrap/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
   <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

   <?php wp_head(); ?>
```

And in the index.php i am using this:

```
    <div class="container">

    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="bootstrap/images/screen1.jpg"/>
    <img src="bootstrap/images/screen2.jpg" />
    <img src="bootstrap/images/screen3.jpg"  />
    <img src="bootstrap/images/screen4.jpg"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am not using anything inside the functions.php file.And am using this inside the style.css:

```
@import url("bootstrap/css/nivo-slider.css");
@import url("bootstrap/css/slider.css");
@import url("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css");
@import url("bootstrap/themes/default/default.css");
```

Could you please tell me where i go wrong due to which the git file is appearing and not the images slideshow. When used as index.html it worked as a charm.

Comment: You called the jquery after the nivo slider also do follow the proper enqueue standards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into the two link might solve the problem if you did with enqueue standards you might solve jquery conflict.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Create a **script.js** file

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
```

Open your theme file functions.php and add the below code:

create function

```
    function enqueue_script_for_nivo () {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // Load your nivo script too here.
   wp_register_script('nivoscript',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"');
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js' );
wp_enqueue_script('nivoscript');
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script');
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_script_for_nivo');
```

That's all try this one hopefully it should work :)

Comment: Should i create the script.js file outside the js folder?

Comment: Any where you can create but one thing you should give a proper path on registering a script

Comment: The browser crashes when the function is added

Comment: can you give me a live site link ?

Comment: No when the function is removed the browser crashes.I am using mamp. So haven't got any live site

Comment: Yes i removed the previous scripts except this in the header:   ' <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

   <?php wp_head(); ?>'

Comment: Thank you so much there was an error in your code () which i added and everything is working fine.